# Value of ancient artifacts

Tags: alternate-history, ancient-history, secret-society

Given a very soft-science world, what value or somewhat logical unobtanium could be found in ancient artifacts from old civilizations. The goal is to have big corporations and secret societies raid tombs for these artifacts. If necessary I don't mind going into a very lightweight magic world, but if I can just keep it at soft science I would prefer that.

Requirements

- The artifacts should be somewhat possible to be created or gathered by ancient civilizations. Handwaving meteors or whatever with special elements is however perfectly fine.
- Forgotten technologies are fine. Doesn't need to historically accurate, as long as it's not entirely impossible.
- In the modern day it should directly or indirectly give power.

Comment: This question looks opinion-based to me. If you are fine with handwaving it could be anything you want. Especially if forgotten technology is fine. Ancient technology would be a perfect plot-hook for having a secret society. I don't see how answers could be rated here.

Comment: @Secespitus What forgotten technology is not entirely impossible and would give power in the modern day? Sure, some Atlantis artifact giving infinite energy is all fun and well, but that's just 101% impossible. I am looking for something that can pass at least some very basic scrutiny.

Comment: This question is too broad. It can be answered by "value of an item is proportional to how useful it is".

Comment: Exactly. You are looking for a plot device that would help you make companies and secret societies interested in raiding tombs and finding these artifacts. That is off-topic on WorldBuilding and whether an answer is good or not depends solely on what you as the author think is appropriate and interesting for your story. The thing about forgotten technology is that we cannot possibly know about it, as it is forgotten. I don't know how to rate answers based on what unobtanium they choose. Giving power directly or indirectly is very broad. I'll see what others think, but IMO this is opinion-based

Comment: @Euphoric If a question can be answered by "value of an item is proportional to how useful it is". Then that isn't too broad, it's quite narrowly defined. Here the criteria for too broad means it needs effectively writing a textbook to answer the question. It's easy to misunderstand what the criteria for too broad or opinion-based are.

Comment: @DavidMulder By now you should understand answers aren't intended to supply the concepts for the kinds of artefacts. It is better if you devise the ancient technology and ask if they would do want them to do, say, as a reality check or whatever other tag would be suitable.

Comment: Hey, ancient artifacts are valuable, even when they are only "special garbage".

Comment: As discussed in previous comments, I'm voting to close, as 'story-based' since this seems like idea generation.

Answer (score 2):

### The Palladium

The walls of [Troy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy) were built by the immortal gods [Poseidon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseidon) and [Apollo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo), who had been [temporarily exiled](http://www.heritage-history.com/?c=read&author=hutchinson&book=porch&story=troy) to the world of the mortals as a punishment for their participation in a conspirancy attempting to overthrow Zeus, the supreme god. The walls were strong, very strong, but they were not the *ultimate* guarantee of security: that was the [*Palladium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palladium_(classical_antiquity)), a wooden statue of [Pallas Athena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallas_Athena), the possession of which guaranteed that the city could not be taken by force of arms.

It actually worked as advertised.

As long as the Palladium was in Troy, all attempts by the Achaeans to take the city failed. [Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odysseus) and [Diomedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diomedes) had to mount a daring commando operation and steal it; Diomedes took the Palladium with him as a spoil of war; we don't precisely know how and why the immensely powerful [*xoanon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xoanon) was brought to Rome.

The Romans kept the Palladium in the [Temple of Vesta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Vesta), one of the most ancient sacred places in the city. It was one of the sacred [*pignora imperii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pignora_imperii), the *securities of power* which guaranteed the rule of Rome over the world.

And Rome stood unconquered for many centuries, but eventually emperor [Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_the_Great) moved the Palladium to Constantinople, were it was buried under the [Column of Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_of_Constantine), inaugurated in 330 CE with a mix of pagan and Christian ceremonies -- one of the last public events where the old religion and the new religion were presented as equals. The columns can still be seen in Istanbul -- the Turks call it the Crooked Stone or the Burnt Pillar.

We don't know what happened to the Palladium after the 4th century. We know that it was eventually removed from Constantinople, because the city fell to the Turks in 1453, which would have been impossible were the Palladium still in the city.

Finding and retrieving the Palladium would be of tremendous importance to any would-be superpower, because its possesion would make their capital city impregable; any enemy would need to physically take possession of the Palladium before they could hope to win.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down.  You could have:

1: **Tech**.  Rayguns.  Rejuvenation chambers.  Yada.  Yada.  My favorite is artificial intelligences difficult to replicate.  They would be old and bizarre.  They might also be bored and happy to be rescued.

2: **Resources.**  Exotic matter is a favorite: superheavy elements, negative matter, antimatter.  Bigass diamonds.  That superdiamond stuff 50% harder than diamonds whose name I can never remember.  Does it begin with L?

**3: Xenobiology.**  Live things or seeds or spores which could be cultivated under the right circumstance to yield some desirable entity or product.  Be careful of those protomolecules now.  Use tongs.

**4:  Cultural / scientific significance.**  These are artifacts whose worth comes from the understanding they shed on the lifeforms that made them.  Museum and collector pieces.  Ojects d'art.

**5:  Religious significance**.  If you are religious and learn that Creation extends beyond what we know, these items might shed light on the Creator or realms of the religious.  It is a continuum between advanced aliens and angels but the secret society angle here could be cool, because many ancient secret societies are also religious societies.  Maybe an opposed society wants to find and destroy such items as heretical?

A good trick to keep the energy moving in your story would be to have the putative reason for tomb raiding be one of these items on the list (maybe a done to death one like exotic tech), but then have it turn out that a subset of tomb raiders are motivated by a different reason on the list.  Milk it: one of the subset of these tomb raiders is actually motivated by a third reason on the list which is the weirdest of all (and maybe he is the weirdest of all).

Answer (score 0):

With some ancient secret technology you are very unlikely to succeed to get power. Any Tech that can be dug up can be replicated, it just takes time. And we probably can make it (a lot) better.

But what if you need some unobtanium that was used to create an artefact? Something only found in meteorites? And that meteorite was used to create something else. I am thinking about this [Egyptian steel](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/06/01/tutankhamuns-blade-made-from-meteorite-study-reveals/). All easily accessible meteorites are used up in the creation of these ancient artefacts. Let's try and grab that stuff.

So, its not the tech itself that has value, its the use as a source material. For, like, [quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing), or AI, etc. *(some handwaving, "These are the materials you are looking for")*

*I don't think museums will like this idea, at all...*